# Assigning variable in IF statement C

Tags: c, variables, if-statement

The code below is to output the time taken for a snail to complete a race. I understand an if statement is to be used however I am struggling to find a way to assign my final code- TimeMinutes1 + TimeMinutes2 + TimeMinutes3 + TimeMinutes4, TimeSeconds1 + TimeSeconds2 + TimeSeconds3 + TimeSeconds4 a variable which can be used in conjunction with an IF statement?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char SquirrelName [20]; 
    int TimeMinutes1;
    int TimeMinutes2;
    int TimeMinutes3;
    int TimeMinutes4;
    int TimeSeconds1;
    int TimeSeconds2;
    int TimeSeconds3;
    int TimeSeconds4;
    int TotalSeconds1;
    int TotalSeconds2;
    int TotalSeconds3;
    int TotalSeconds4;

    printf("What is the name of the squirrel? \n");
    scanf("%s", SquirrelName);

    printf("How long did it take to complete the first lap in Seconds? \n");
    scanf("%d", &TotalSeconds1);

    TimeMinutes1 = TotalSeconds1 / 60;
    TimeSeconds1 = TotalSeconds1 % 60;

    printf("Lap 1 finished in %d minutes and %d seconds\n", TimeMinutes1, TimeSeconds1);

    printf("How long did it take to complete the second lap in Seconds? \n");
    scanf("%d", &TotalSeconds2);

    TimeMinutes2 = TotalSeconds2 / 60;
    TimeSeconds2 = TotalSeconds2 % 60;

    printf("Lap 2 finished in %d minutes and %d seconds\n", TimeMinutes2, TimeSeconds2);

    printf("How long did it take to complete the third lap in Seconds? \n");
    scanf("%d", &TotalSeconds3);

    TimeMinutes3 = TotalSeconds3/ 60;
    TimeSeconds3 = TotalSeconds3 % 60;

    printf("Lap 3 finished in %d minutes and %d seconds\n", TimeMinutes3, TimeSeconds3);

    printf("How long did it take to complete the fourth lap in Seconds? \n");
    scanf("%d", &TotalSeconds4);

    TimeMinutes4 = TotalSeconds4 / 60;
    TimeSeconds4 = TotalSeconds4 % 60;

    printf("Lap 4 finished in %d minutes and %d seconds\n", TimeMinutes4, TimeSeconds4);

    printf("The total time it took for the course to complete was %d minutes and %d seconds\n", TimeMinutes1 + TimeMinutes2 + TimeMinutes3 + TimeMinutes4, TimeSeconds1 + TimeSeconds2 + TimeSeconds3 + TimeSeconds4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @itsme86 made this program using c

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the if statement would do? (And specifically what you need to do but you can't?) You can store those both in separate variables, and you can add the minutes * 60 to the seconds if you want just a single seconds total to test (or just add up the original TotalSeconds)

Comment: Can you describe in words what you want to do?

Comment: Note that as it stands you may get an invalid number of seconds in your total here already, e.g. if all four times were 45 seconds you'll get total = 0 minutes and 180 seconds. You probably need to recompute the minutes / seconds split of the total rather than just add up the numbers you have so far.

Comment: @Rup Alright so the if statement needs to display whether the time the course completed was below 4 minutes. If so the snail would have qualified for the next competition.

Comment: Then I think the easiest thing to do then would be to just add up TotalSeconds1+2+3+4 and check if that's less than 4*60. But as above you probably need to do that anyway, so that you can print the total time properly divided into minutes and seconds, and if you do compute the total time in minutes and seconds you could instead just test minutes < 4 if it's strictly less than four minutes.

Comment: Have you learned about writing functions yet?  If so, your code would benefit from using some functions rather than writing out almost the same code 4 times.

Comment: @Rup Oh yeah I see that thanks. However when doing so how would I assign the variables where it becomes a single variable, all the minutes and seconds I have added up?

Comment: The same as you've done already? Declare `int RaceTotalSeconds, RaceMinutes, RaceSeconds;` and then when you have the lap times `RaceTotalSeconds = TotalSeconds1 + TotalSeconds2 + TotalSeconds3 + TotalSeconds4; RaceMinutes = RaceTotalSeconds / 60; RaceSeconds = RaceTotalSeconds % 60;`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Nope have only just started programming.

Comment: Yes, add up total seconds and divide by 60 to get total minutes -- being integers, the resulting value will round down automatically

Comment: `totalSeconds = TotalSeconds1 + TotalSeconds2 + TotalSeconds3 + TotalSeconds4; if (totalSeconds < 240) { printf("Snail or Squirrel or whatever qualified!\n"); }`

Comment: If you've not learned about writing and using functions you've written, then it's OK (mostly) to do as you've done.  Have you learned about arrays?  Again, there could be ways to write less code if you use arrays and loops instead of writing almost the same code out 4 times.  And, again, if you've not learned about them, so be it; they're on the agenda in the not very distant future, as is the writing and use of functions other than `main()`.

Comment: @Rup Thanks for the help the code works perfectly

Comment: @TormundGiantsbane Thanks for the help

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks I will definitely look more into it.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there are multiple/many variables ending in a digit, such as `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3`, etc. this indicates that we should be using an array [and a loop instead of replicating the code].

If we have multiple parallel arrays that are indexed by the same index variable, such as:

```
#define LAPCOUNT    4
int time_tot[LAPCOUNT];
int time_min[LAPCOUNT];
int time_sec[LAPCOUNT];
```

This indicates we should create a `struct` and have an array of these structs.

Here is a version of your code that uses these ideas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int time_tot;
    int time_min;
    int time_sec;
} lap_t;

#define LAPCOUNT    4

int
main(void)
{
    char SquirrelName[20];
    int lapidx;
    lap_t *lap;
    lap_t laplist[LAPCOUNT];
    lap_t laptot;

    printf("What is the name of the squirrel? \n");
    scanf("%s", SquirrelName);

    for (lapidx = 0;  lapidx < LAPCOUNT;  ++lapidx) {
        lap = &laplist[lapidx];

        printf("How long did it take to complete lap %d in Seconds? \n",
            lapidx + 1);

        scanf("%d", &lap->time_tot);

        lap->time_min = lap->time_tot / 60;
        lap->time_sec = lap->time_tot % 60;

        printf("Lap %d finished in %d minutes and %d seconds\n",
             lapidx + 1,lap->time_min, lap->time_sec);
    }

    laptot.time_min = 0;
    laptot.time_sec = 0;
    laptot.time_tot = 0;

    for (lapidx = 0;  lapidx < LAPCOUNT;  ++lapidx) {
        lap = &laplist[lapidx];
        laptot.time_min += lap->time_min;
        laptot.time_sec += lap->time_sec;
        laptot.time_tot += lap->time_tot;
    }

#if 0
    printf("The total time it took for the course to complete was %d minutes and %d seconds\n",
        laptot.time_min,laptot.time_sec);
#else
    laptot.time_min = laptot.time_tot / 60;
    laptot.time_sec = laptot.time_tot / 60;
    printf("The total time it took for the course to complete was %d minutes and %d seconds\n",
        laptot.time_min,laptot.time_sec);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Thanks I’ll definitely look more into this

It's an important concept for the future.

Using an array *would* have become more obvious if the lap count were larger, say, 100 instead of just 4.

When designing an algorithm, an important question to ask oneself is: *Does my solution "scale" [up]?*

A `struct` is like a form or [database] record. It brings all related things together. A form is a single piece of paper that has all information about a given topic (e.g. a tax form or personnel record).

Consider a simple personnel record:

```
typedef struct {
    char person_name[100];
    char person_street[100];
    char person_city[100];
    char person_state[2];
    char person_telno[10];
    int person_age;
    float person_salary;
} person;
```

This is like having a single page per person, and the employee file contains all such pages.

*Without* the `struct` idea, we'd need separate file folders for each of the above record "fields"

Names:

```
Smith, John
Jones, Fred
Miller, Mary
```

Streets:

```
123 Main St
235 Elm St
63 Oak Ave
```

Cities:

```
New York
Chicago
Los Angeles
```

Using the `struct`, our organization would look more like:

```
Smith, John     123 Main St     New York
Jones, Fred     235 Elm St      Chicago
Miller, Mary    63 Oak Ave      Los Angeles
```

In these real world terms, of course, this data organization seems obvious. But, when coding, particularly for things that are more abstract, it can sometimes be obscured by the complexity of the problem.

Being able to refine/reduce the code [often my ensuring that the data structures used are minimal and complete], can keep the code simple, clean, and robust.

This can even happen to experienced programmers. In a real commercial product I worked on, I found "parallel arrays" being used. I refactored the code to use an array of a new `struct` I created. I did this just to simplify/cleanup the code. In the process, I was able to uncover and fix at least five bugs that were latent and not obvious until the cleanup.

Comment: Thanks I’ll definitely look more into this

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do is something like this:

> If the total time is less than 4 minutes then display a message

When you word it in English like this, it helps make it easier to translate into code. First we need to calculate the total time. You can do that with a single assignment:

```
int total = TotalSeconds1 + TotalSeconds2 + TotalSecond3 + TotalSeconds4;
```

Now we can write an if statement. One way to do this is to convert 4 minutes into seconds, but I'm too lazy to do this by hand, so I write it explicitly in the code:

```
if (total <= 4 * 60) {
    printf("You qualified!")
}
```

Of course, you can change the message here to suit your needs.

A few suggestions:

1. **Use meaningful variable names.** For the most part, you do this very well. My only suggestion here is to use `lap1`, `lap2`, etc. instead of `TotalSeconds1`.
2. **Learn about loops.** I understand that you are new to programming. If you haven't yet learned about `for` and `while` loops, I'm sure they are coming up in the class. These are great tools that allow you to write less code for repeated tasks.
3. **Learn about arrays.** In the same vein as #2, arrays allow you to store lists of data with a single variable. Whenever you find yourself naming variables with numbers on the end, you should most likely use an array instead.